# how to maintain session id in mobile application with titanium

Tags: session, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have just started to  developping a mobile geolocation application( with Titanium(android +iphone).The problem is how to maintain the session id of the user after logging.

Comment: Can you provide more details? How are you storing sessions now?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
App.Properties.setString('sID', '1234');
Ti.API.info('The value of the givenName property is: ' + Ti.App.Properties.getString('sID'));
```

Thanks